# mongodb aggregation with $last,$first updating values with zero if no record found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Please check this query

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            "userId" : ObjectId("5e7147ada3141a63a0dbc154"),
        "adminId" :  ObjectId("5e7147e8fc64ed3d2473o2fec"),
            '$or': [{
                    'orderedOnDate': ISODate("2020-03-21T00:00:00Z")
                    }, 
                     {
                      'orderedOnDate': ISODate("2020-03-14T00:00:00Z")
                    }]
              }
         }, 
        {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$totalOrders',
          },
        },
       {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'code': '$totalOrders.code',
                'date': '$orderedOnDate',
            },
            'orderCount': {
                '$last': '$totalOrders.orderCount',
            },
             'sortedDate': {
                '$last': '$orderedOnDate'
            }
        }
    }
    , {
        '$sort': {
            'sortedDate': 1
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$_id.code',
            'orderCount': {
                '$last': '$orderCount'
            },
            'previousOrderCount': {
                '$first': '$previousOrderCount'
            },
           'sortedDate': {
                '$last': '$sortedDate'
            },
            'previousSortedDate': {
                '$first': '$sortedDate'
            },

        }
    },
      {
        '$project': {
            "_id": 0,
           'code':1
            'sortedDate': 1,
            'orderCount': 1,
            'previousWeekCount': [
                {
                    'sortedDate': '$previousOrderCount',
                    'orderCount': '$previousOrderCount',

                }
            ]
        }
    }])
```

In the above query i am trying to fetch the data for tomorrow date and D-7 date, the query works as expected if it finds record for both the dates, now the issue comes up when there is no record for D-7th day then $first and $last has the same date hence it shows the same data in previousWeekCount too. But i want to insert 0 value if there is no record for D-7th day.Also i need to maintain the $project structure as it has be sent to the frontend.I had tried few things like $ifnull , also tried $cond on date but nothing worked any suggestions or how it can be tackled .Below is sample document which does not have a record of D-7th date

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e73089d44eb7a50708167fc"),
    "orderedOnDate" : ISODate("2020-03-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
     "totalOrders" : [
            {      
                "orderCount" : 10,
                "code" : "#001",
            },
            {      
                "orderCount" : 46,
                "code" : "#002",
            },
    ],
}
```

Now if there is no record of D-7th day can i show orderCount :0 against the codes, i donot want to save the document of D-7th just need show 0 values

Comment: When you use `$last` in `$group` then you should sort the documents beforehand, otherwise the order is undetermined. Perhaps `$max` or `$min` would be an alternative.

Comment: @ – Wernfried Domscheit $max,$min okay  where while i am matching the docs?? And beforehand u meant i should use $sort before $group right??

Comment: Yes, you have to $sort before $group. $max or $min would be ok for `'$orderedOnDate'` but `'$totalOrders.orderCount'` requires proper sorting I guess

Comment: Instead of `$or: [...]` you could also use `orderedOnDate: { $in: [ISODate("2020-03-21T00:00:00Z"), ISODate("2020-03-14T00:00:00Z")] }` - but this is more cosmetic.

Comment: @- Wernfried Domscheit but it would result in the same issue i  guess if there is no record of D-7th day it would show the same orderCount in the previousWeekCount but i want yo show 0 values if there is no record of D-7th day how min and max will help?

Comment: In your `$group` you have `orderedOnDate` at `_id` and as accumulator, this does not make much sense. For me it is not clear what you try to get. Please provide 1-2 more sample input documents.

Comment: sure afk for 15min lets continue in chat after

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210006/discussion-between-sachin-and-wernfried-domscheit).

Answer (score 0):

Usually I refuse an answer when sample input data and **expected result** are not provided. However, this aggregation should give you an idea for a solution. Usually whenever I have to work with Date values then I prefer using the [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         userId: ObjectId("5e7147ada3141a63a0dbc154"),
         orderedOnDate: { $in: [moment.utc().startOf('day').toDate(), moment.utc().startOf('day').subtract(7, 'days').toDate()] }
      }
   },
   { $sort: { orderedOnDate: 1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         lastWeekOrders: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
         todayOrders: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         lastWeekOrders: {
            $cond: {
               if: { $eq: ["$lastWeekOrders.orderedOnDate", moment.utc().startOf('day').subtract(7, 'days').toDate()] },
               then: "$lastWeekOrders",
               else: {
                  orderedOnDate: moment.utc().startOf('day').subtract(7, 'days').toDate(),
                  totalOrders: [{ orderCount: 0 }]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         todayOrders: {
            $cond: {
               if: { $eq: ["$todayOrders.orderedOnDate", moment.utc().startOf('day').toDate()] },
               then: "$todayOrders",
               else: {
                  orderedOnDate: moment.utc().startOf('day').toDate(),
                  totalOrders: [{ orderCount: 0 }]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
])
```